# ログイン後、rootのルーティングへ遷移し、ユーザーが登録したタスクを一覧表示する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ログイン後、タスクリスト一覧に飛ぶ方法がわからないです。

**app/view/tasks/index**

```html
<h1>タスクリスト一覧</h1>
<ul>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <li><%= link_to task.id, task %> : <%= task.status %> &gt; <li><%= task.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to '新規タスクの投稿', new_task_path %>
```

**config/rootes**

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: 'tasks#index'

  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :tasks
  get 'login', to:'tasks#index'
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
end
```

**app/controllers/sessions_controllers**

```ruby
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    email = params[:session][:email].downcase
    password = params[:session][:password]
    if login(email, password)
      flash[:success] = 'ログインに成功しました。'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'ログインに失敗しました。'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:success] = 'ログアウトしました。'
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

  def login(email, password)
    @user = User.find_by(email: email)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(password)
      # ログイン成功
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      return true
    else
      # ログイン失敗
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/sessions/new**

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Log in</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">

    <%= form_with(url: login_path, scope: :session, local: true) do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email, 'Email' %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password, 'Password' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <%=  f.submit 'Log in', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config/routes.rbの`get 'login', to:'tasks#index'`の行は不要です。
app/controllers/sessions_controllers.rbの`redirect_to @user`は`redirect_to root_url`とすると良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！直したところできました！